# I want to hide json file from public access. How do I do that?

Tags: php, json, apache, .htaccess

I got a website, and the javascript file is loading a json file(using getJson) into options of one select element based on previous select option.

But in the mean time, public can access that json file directly.

I only want server can access this file and loads corresponding options in theselect element. But I don't want public can access that json file directly(avoid them downloading and such..)

How do I do this? Via htaccess? or sth else? I tried 'FILES' rule in htaccess but the server cannot access the json file either.

Comment: I saw sth called crossorigin specified in <script type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous"> will this be useful to protecting json data?

Comment: You can put the JSON data in a DB, or you can put the file outside the web root. That way, people can only get pieces of the data upon request. I'm honestly not sure what you'd want to do that though.

Comment: I might just try to move it outside web root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript running at client side, so your visitor can get any resource used by javascript.
If you want to hide anything, you need to replace your javascript code by server-side generation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot protect json data. If the public cannot access the data then your page also cannot access it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check ip of requester at the top of your json file
if it's not your server then exit

This is example

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '190.180.0.1')
exit ('You can not use this file');
```

and sure you have to replace ip with your server ip

i missed this part (and the javascript file is loading )

sure the above code will no't work because java script is client side
so if you blocked all requests except your server then your users also can't load this file

Answer (score 0):

You can't really protect data that you have sent to the client browser. A determined user will be able to locate it. So, your best option is to do your filtering and other logic on the server before sending the data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Apache you could use mod_rewrite. I am not sure but I think the rule would look like, RewriteRule ^(myfile.json) - [F,L,NC]

Answer (score 0):

Access restriction by encryption could work IF the DB is supposed to be read from a client - just encrypt the entire content of the JSON & decrypt in the client, with a user password. As long as we still have the Right to Encrypt.

Comment: may I add a question to this answer? Is it possible to connect to an online DB from a localhosted client?